# Config Visual studio code terminal for Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, config

I am trying to start mongod.exe from Powershell terminal in Visual studio code

`directory/bin/mongod.exe --path=/directory/mongodb-data`

Then I got many lines like this:

`{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-06T10:02:45.286+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLorce-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-06T10:02:45.624+07:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configuretworkInterface startup"}`

How can I configure the terminal to display like below(with keys or fields removed):

`2021-07-06T10:02:45.286 I CONTROL [main] Automatically disabling TLorce-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'`

Answer (score 0):

The log format changed from plain text to JSON style in Mongo version 4.4

You can use [jq tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to reformat the messages.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.